# flutter website and apps using MVC and flutter how do I connect back end?

Tags: flutter

hi I want to develop flutter apps in ios and android and website for the same.
 is it ok to use futter in this case?
is website also needs to develop in flutter ?
is it ok if i develop website in codeigniter or laravel?
which one i need to start first?

how can I use flutter development for both apps and website?

I am building a flutter project and am having an issue integrating the web and mobile code in a single project. will it work?
or Do I need to build separate project ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't think there is a right or wrong for this answer because it can work for sure but it depends how you implement it.

To your first question if you only need one codebase the answer is YesNo. This means you need for the entire business logic only one code base BUT (and this is were my clients are always doing it wrong too) you need most of the time two different UIs. One for the mobile versions and one for the desktop version.

To your second question if you can use laravel for it. My answer: Sure why not? You can use any database system for it as long as you are able to integrate it into your flutter application there shouldnt be any restriction from the flutter side.

To your explicit thrid question if you need to have seperate projects. As I said, you have the same business logic but two or more UIs.This means you need only one project!

Hope this answers your questions ;)